# Anchor tag with id only works when i do "open in a new tab"

Tags: html, anchor

I have a very strange problem, i have a div with an anchor tag with an id in it, when i click on the anchor tag, it doesnt open the link in it, but if i right click it and open it in a new tab, it works perfectly, do you guys know why is that ?

here is my exemple :

```
<div class="toto">
  <a id="tutu" href="https://www.google.com" >my cocorico</a>
  <div>
    cocorico
  </div>
 </div>
```

here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mog8zf3t/5/

Answer (score 2):

This issue is caused by using jsfiddle rather than your html.

The code runs in an iframe on jsfiddle and Google have specifically blocked you from being able to do this by setting 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Either try running the code on your local machine or pick a different website which will allow you to display it in an iframe.

Comment: you're right, it's just google that doesn't work on jsfiddle, but i had the same problem on my local machine, and it happens that i had a `event.preventDefault();` on the click of the anchor tag, and that's why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function go_to_href(href){
  window.open(href,'_blank')

}
```

```css
.toto{
    background: grey;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    }
.toto a {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="toto" onClick="go_to_href('https://www.google.com')">
  <a id="tutu" href="">my cocorico</a>
  <div class="eps-Chip-content">
    cocorico
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is cause of frames and iframes. Two things.1 is same thing as @hairmot said. sameorigin.

But second reason is when you have your main site an `https` site like `https://jsfiddle.net/mog8zf3t/7/` you cant have http links there. So you cant for example open an `http://jsfiddle.net` link on that page. So in real time usage you should consider both.

So in order to observe the reason this is what you can do. open inspect element on your browser go to console section. try to click on link and check the error.

> for the fiddlejs code you provide the error is cause of same origin
>   problem ( the link you provide is not from same origin as the main
>   site).

Comment: dear downvoter can you explain reason why you put downvotes?

Comment: i think it was because i had `https` on my anchor tag and not an `http`, but thank yo tough for your answer

Comment: @DhonJoeok ok but i mentioned that. and also i told you how you can find the real reason

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers, i found the problem, and it was in my js, i had a `event.preventDefault();` on the click of the anchor tag, and that's why it wasn't working. take it of and it works perfectly.

here is where i found my answer : https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had `data-toggle="buttons"` in the surrounding `<div>` which I discovered after a few frustrating hours. Posting as an answer as it may be helpful for someone.